# Row Truncated Between Pages

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

As shown in the images below sometimes the rows are truncated/split beteween two pages of my report.

Is there any property I can set on DevExpress XtraReport to avoid it?

**Details:**

The DetailBand contains 3 fields and is inside a subreport (it's a 2 columns/subreport).

The subreport is printed inside a GroupHeader in the MainReport.

The truncated text reads (in 3 columns):

> 343
>
> HONORÁRIOS - FREE LANCERS
>
> R$ 2.126,42

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happened I found the issue.
My databands all have the flag **KeepTogether** set to true but labels also have that flag (default false).
I flipped the flag to true in all labels in the report and it worked